# Is there any instant voting poll creator online?

Tags: webapp-rec

I would like to create voting polls with shortened URLs like this:

```
http://instantpool.com/b5aH3   (not a real site)
```

It will open a web page where the you can vote on a specific subject and show the results.

Comment: why close this? its a good question. good way to know best matching web tool. there is lots of similar questions at stackoverflow. best IDE for cmake for example

Comment: @Serg they say: Please note that the following subjects are considered off-topic here: Web application recommendation requests, Software Recommendations ( https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ ) may be suited - please review their policies before posting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doodle.com allows you to schedule events or create polls of any kinds.

See their example test poll at :
http://www.doodle.com/BSPafv8m95xnewtg

Comment: also available with a new design: http://www.doodle.com/BSPafv8m95xnewtg?newDesign=true

Answer (score 0):

[Epicpoll.me](http://epicpoll.me) or [strawpoll.me](http://strawpoll.me) is what you need. Both are simple and good.